# Android: open folder dialog

Tags: android, file, directory

I have the following code to open a folder in Android, and although I see a lot of posts mentioning it works I am unable to get it working.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myFolder");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

It just opens the root folder (in this case, /storage/sdcard and not /storage/sdcard/myfolder).

Anyone knows why?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) to use the `Uri` portion of an `Intent`. While there may be some apps with activities that support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, many will not.

Moreover, Android does not really work with "folders", and so there will not necessarily be *any* app on a device that will allow you to browse arbitrary stuff.

You are welcome to use [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on Android 4.4+, which is Google's approach to dealing with a central system UI for the users browsing content from multiple sources.

Or, there are plenty of [file and directory picker libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).